# How to create xmlns:xsi and xsd information in an XML document

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-xe

I have a Delphi XE application that reads a validated XML file, modifies it and then saves it.  The saved version can be validated.  I use SML Spy to create the file and to validate it.

Now I need to create a document in memory and save it. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to generate the xmlns and xsd information attributes to the document so that it can be validated.

Comment: Which XML library are you using? They vary in design.

Comment: I'm using TXMLDocument that is part of Delphi XE.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, despite my comment above I found that the easiest way to do it was not with `DeclareNamespace`.

Here's an example that doesn't even use a `TXMLDocument` on the form. Just add `xmldom`, `XMLIntf`, and `XMLDoc`  to your implementation uses clause (`Xml.xmldom` , `Xml.XMLIntf`, and `Xml.XMLDoc` for XE2), and then this works:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  TheDoc: IXmlDocument;
  iNode: IXmlNode;
  xmlText: DOMString;
begin
  TheDoc := NewXMLDocument;
  TheDoc.Version := '1.0';
  TheDoc.Encoding := 'UTF-16';
  iNode := TheDoc.AddChild('test:test_file');
  iNode.SetAttributeNS('xmlns:test', '', 'http://www.foo.com' );
  iNode.SetAttributeNS('xmlns:xsi', '', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
  TheDoc.SaveToXML(xmlText);
  Memo1.Lines.Text := xmlText;
end;
```

The above results in this output in the `TMemo`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<test:test_file xmlns:test="http://www.foo.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
```

Comment: That did it.  It was a bit confusing because your example had two xmlDoc's (one in the uses clause and one in the button Var) but after I sorted that out - sweet